# encode image in to base64 not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('course_profile_image'))
        {

            error($this->upload->display_errors(),TRUE,400);
        }else{
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            $filename=$data['upload_data']['file_name'];
            $pathinfo = 'dist/img/courseimage/'.$filename;
            $filetype = pathinfo($pathinfo, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $filecontent = file_get_contents($pathinfo);

            try{
                $base64=rtrim(base64_encode($filecontent)); 

            }catch(Exception $e){
                error($e,TRUE,855);


            }
            $image = 'data: '.mime_content_type($pathinfo).';base64,'.$base64;
```

It's converting the image into the base64 but when large dimensions images uploaded it covets only half or some part of it. I am storing this base64 in to mysql database column type text.

Comment: dont store the image in the db, save the path to the file

Comment: i know but need to store it in database. how can i store file path when its converted in to the base64.

Comment: Can you show your table definition for where you are trying to store it? It could be that MySQL is truncating it.

Comment: you are encoding the file content, not the file name, just use `move_uploaded_file()` and then save the path in a varchar column https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Answer (score 0):

> Change your database field type from **text** to **mediumText**
>   because TEXT has only 64 KiB length so it not store your full base 64
>   code.